# Android Edit Text error overlaps other components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, overlapping

I have a problem that error message displayed by edit text overlaps other components on layout.

[image]

Does anybody have an idead how to display error message behind top and bottom layouts?

Little bit about structure:
Top red and bottom grey parts Linear Layouts. Main middle content is Frame Layout, whose content is handled by application. In this case there are several edit texts wrapped in Scroll View.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.CustomDrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.custom.TitlebarLayout
        android:id="@+id/titlebarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <com.custom.ButtonsToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside contentContainer is below layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         xmlns:msa="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".fragment.addressedit.AddressEditFragment"
         android:id="@+id/frame_layout_address_edit">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_address_dialog"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout_address_top"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:tag="etx_name1"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_name2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_name"
            android:hint="Name2"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:tag="etx_name2"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_street"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_name2"
            android:hint="Street"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:tag="etx_street"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_houseno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_street"
            android:hint="House No."
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            msa:alternativeInputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:tag="etx_house_no"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_postcode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_houseno"
            android:hint="Postcode"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:tag="etx_postcode1"
            msa:validation="postcode"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_postcode"
            android:hint="City"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:tag="etx_city"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_city"
            android:hint="Country"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:tag="etx_country"/>

        <com.custom.editview.EditViewLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_address_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_address_country"
            android:hint="Phone"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:tag="etx_phone1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: could you please share the code in description

Comment: What do you mean by behind of top and bottom layout? Is it mean at the end of the edit text? If so, you can implement a custom text view at the end of your edit text layout. You can devide your edit text and text view using relative layout with fixed size or even use horizontal linear layout with weight

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono in the attached screenshot you can see that on second picture is error message displayed over red top bar. I expect that error will be displayed behind red part (so on second image won't be any error message visible)

Answer (score 2):

Just do a simple tweak and you're good to go..

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            addressName.clearFocus();
            addressName2.clearFocus();
            houseNo.clearFocus();
            phone.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
    })
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Give the error to TextInputLayout.

```
...
    txtInputLayout.setErrorEnabled();
    txtInputLayout.setError("error text");
...
```

and the error will be displayed under edittext.

Comment: I don't want to display it under edit text, I want to display it behind top red and bottom grey layouts.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to resolve your prob.

1. Use Toast

   ```
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), validate_msz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ```
2. Use Relative Layout To set your error message layout to bottom and top

   ```
   <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >
    <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:gravity="bottom"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="0dp">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_password_save"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="#e91043"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:paddingBottom="0dp"
       android:text="SAVE "
       android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

     </LinearLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. Use Floating action Button according to your need.

   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html
4. Custom Dialog box.

Comment: @swiki , use only this in LinearLayout inside relative android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="bottom"

Comment: Maybe I used wrong word in question. I mean display behind top and bottom layouts, bot under :) ... I would like to display it behind when scrolling up/down - not in a front of these layouts.